# How to make look and feel of RichTextFx similar to TextArea?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, richtextfx

RichTextFx (top control) doesn't looks like TextArea (bottom control) by default:

[image: RichTextFX without border, corners and focus border]

I have found a way how to add round corners (just copy and configure [some styles](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L1297-L1330) from modena.css):

```
.virtualized-scroll-pane {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-cursor: default;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        derive(-fx-base,-1%);
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 2;
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0;
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane > .corner {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 0;
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane .code-area {
    /*the is 1px less top and bottom than TextInput because of scrollpane border */
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.583em 0.25em 0.583em; /* 3 7 3 7 */
    -fx-cursor: text;
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 4px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -8%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane:focused .code-area {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 2, 1, 0;
}
```

but don't understand how to add gray border around unfocused control and blue border around focused control (i.e. around text control and scrollbars)?

Seems like blue border of focused control configured [here](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L1266-L1289) but the following CSS doesn't work:

```
.virtualized-scroll-pane {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
    -fx-highlight-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-20%);
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-cursor: text;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.583em 0.333333em 0.583em; /* 4 7 4 7 */
}
.virtualized-scroll-pane:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: -fx-accent;
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

As I understand this is doesn't work because `.virtualized-scroll-pane` doesn't take focus.

[Here](https://github.com/maxd/richtextfx-as-textarea) is Maven project for reproduce problem.

So, how to fix it?

FYI: RichTextFX 0.7-M1, JDK 1.8.0_91-b14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following ways to customize RichTextFx:

For 0.6.10 version:

```
.code-area {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-padding: 0.041666625em;
}

.code-area:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
}

.code-area .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 2;
}

.code-area .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0;
}
```

[image: richtextfx-0.6.10-without-selection]
[image: richtextfx-0.6.10-with-selection]

For 0.7-M1 (with fix for 'focused' pseudo class):

```
.virtualized-scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
}

.virtualized-scroll-pane:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
}

/* 
I don't understand why this rule fix problem with border around CodeArea.
May be somebody can explain it.
*/
.virtualized-scroll-pane .styled-text-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0px;
}

.virtualized-scroll-pane .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 2;

    -fx-padding: 0 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em;
}

.virtualized-scroll-pane .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0;

    -fx-padding: 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0.08333325em 0;
}
```

[image: richtextfx-0.7-M1-without-selection]
[image: richtextfx-0.7-M1-with-selection]

Full versions available in [repository](https://github.com/maxd/richtextfx-as-textarea) in separated branches.

Unresolved problems:

- scroll bars size
- color of square in right-bottom corner
- indent before and on the top of text

May be somebody can provide better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually toggle the `focused` pseudo class of the `VirtualizedScrollPane` and then you can use the `.virtualized-scroll-pane:focused` selector in CSS:

```
PseudoClass FOCUSED = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("focused");
area.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    virtualizedScrollPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(FOCUSED, newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the color of the square in the right-bottom corner use this:

```
.virtualized-scroll-pane  .scroll-pane .filler {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.virtualized-scroll-pane  .scroll-pane .corner {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```